# How do I query the dates in mongodb such that the entries with less than 1 hour difference is removed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[MongoDB collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbLVS.png)

I have this collection. I want to query entries so that either one of key "2" or "3" would be removed because the createdAt entries have a difference less than 1 hour. What would be the query?

Comment: if you can give the data in text json so people can test their queries, it also helps a lot if you give the expected results in text json also, so people know exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- uses `$dateTrunc` with unit hour, that means keep the date as it is, but make zero all the left after the date
- group by that trunc date => dates with same hour are in the same group
- keep only one of them

*query doesn't work with difference, it works by same hour, for example `1:01` is the same with `1:59` but `1:59` is not same group with `2:01`

*difference is complicated i think, because 2 dates can have difference 1 hour, and be in different days, months, or even years,
also we have to decide which ones to keep, in case of chains of dates.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70411011-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group":
  {"_id":{"$dateTrunc":{"date":"$createdAt", "unit":"hour"}},
   "doc":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$doc"}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$gt` query. See the document [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/)

And here is a code example. Just change the places with your property, which is `createdAt` in your scenario.

```
let user = await User.deleteMany({
    createdAt: { $gt: Date.now() - 3600000 } // 3600000 means 1 hour in millisecond
});

// Rest of your code
```